# incorrect display of data type in dbeaver

Tags: sql, dbeaver, greenplum

So, I convert dataframe with float64 columns to sql and get "text" column type

```
a:text
1.11
0
4
123.43
[NULL]
2
```

But i can use this "text" as numbers, for example, i can

```
SELECT sum(a) result_cmn from tb
SELECT a+1 result_cmn from tb
```

and it received absolutely correct answer, lol, from text, moreover `result_cmn`s became numeric!

Is there way to fix this small bug(???)?

Comment: this is a wanted and explained behaviour, most databases have an automatic conversion to fit the query, you need to cast or convert it back

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with dbeaver and is instead implicit casting being performed by greenplum.